# Access denied in windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

Why am I getting an error in this code?

```
 StorageFolder folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
 StorageFile sampleFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("sample.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Error:

> Additional information: Acces denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

In Windows store app and how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

**You should not (or cannot) use app installed location to create files because it is read-only.**

If you want to create app files you should use another directory like:

`StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder:`